# DateTime not calling when posting to CSV file from php form

Tags: php, csv

I am new to php and java etc, so i'm hacking it as i'm learning, but i've looked at every possible option and tried to adjust, but for some reason my code is still not working. I am calling the date and time in php file, and it submits the date and time to the email, but does not place it in my csv file (leaves a blank column).

I set the date and time with the first line and then the csv submit is after that (so i do not call the date and time via my html or anything

php

```
    $combinedDT = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("$date $time"));

//start of the csv submission form

$filename = "wedding_website_email_form.csv";
$string = array($_POST['combinedDT'],$_POST['name_surname'],$_POST['telephone'],$_POST['email_from'],$_POST['rsvp'],$_POST['attendees'],$_POST['song'],$_POST['comments']);  

if (file_exists($filename)) {
        $file = fopen($filename, 'a');
        fputcsv($file, $string );
    } else {
        $file = fopen($filename, 'a'); 
        $head_data=array("combinedDT","name_surname","telephone","email_from","rsvp","attendees","song","comments");
        fputcsv($file,$head_data);
        fputcsv($file, $string );
    }

fclose($file);
```

Is there a different way to call it than to the email function that works?

Comment: What does your POST array look like? Is `$_POST['combinedDT']` set? Should `$_POST['combinedDT']` instead be `$combinedDT`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're calculating

`$combinedDT = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("$date $time"));`

But then calling the line for your CSV from the global `$_POST` variable, not the locally calculated variable.

`$string = array($combinedDT, $_POST['name_surname']....);`

Should enter the locally calculated DateTime into the CSV.

Comment: Thank you soooooooo much!!!!!! That is exactly what i needed! Thought I still had to use POST because it's not in that part of code. Worked like a charm when i did it your way! :) And so I learn!